# Unable to get InternalServerException Content

Tags: c#, moq, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, mstest

Controller snippet:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MyMethod()
{
   try
   {
       //Do Stuff....
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
      return HandleException(e);
   }
}
```

HandleException Snippet...

```
public static HttpResponseMessage HandleException(Exception e)
{
    //Bunch of unrelated stuff...
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError) 
               { 
                   Content = new StringContent(e.Message)
               };
}
```

Unit Test Snippet...

```
public async Task Test_InternalServerError()
{
   Mock<IBusinessObject> boMocked = new Mock<IBusinessObject>();
   Exception mockedException = new Exception("This is a mocked exception");
   boMocked.Setup(x => x.MyMethod()).ThrowsAsync(mockedException);

   MyController controller = new MyController(boMocked.Object);

   IHttpActionResult actionResult = await controller.MyMethod();
   ExceptionResult contentResult = actionResult as ExceptionResult;

   Assert.IsTrue(contentResult.Exception.Message == mockedException.Message);

}
```

For the above unit test I am running into an issue where contentResult is always coming back as NULL.

Action result is returning an object of type ResponseMessageResult with the correct status code of 500.  It seems like it does not like the case to ExceptionResult but I swear this was working for me a few months ago.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: The exception is being caught and the value of the HandleException method is being returned, which is an HttpResponseMessage.  Have you tried having the HandleException method return an ExceptionResult explicitly?

Comment: The Handler also handles NotFound, BadRequest, and a few other codes so ExceptionResult won't work.  The handler is kind of a catch all exception and has logic in it to mask or allow a message to the client.  For example. when an AuthenticationException is handled it logs the actually message on our side but the client simply gets an Unauthorized message with no details.

Comment: Then I'd change the test to make sure a Result with a status code of 500 is returned.

Comment: I think I might have to run with that.  This was working but sometime over the last 2 months it stopped.  I liked having the ability to verify that the exception I am getting is actually the one I am throwing.